# Can I display:none part of a jQuery UI draggable and still keep the cursor in place somehow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a number of draggables with images in them that I want to drop into folders.  To conserve space (and make more draggables visible on the screen at one time), I'm hiding the images with CSS during the drag.  How can I keep the mouse on the draggable when the images disappear?

Here's an example of what I'm seeing, just using a simple draggable box:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    cursor: "move",
    scroll: false,
    cursorAt: { top: 5, left: 5 },
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $('img').addClass('hidden');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('img').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fBPdF/

The `hidden` class uses `display:none;` to hide the images.  As you can see in the fiddle, dragging the first image works fine, and the mouse tracks along in the upper left-hand corner of the box while you drag.  When you drag the second, the mouse floats off to the side because the cursorAt value has already been set when the images get removed.

I'd prefer not to use a helper clone (because that makes the move look more like a copy), but that's the only way I've found so far to make it work.  I tried resetting the cursorAt inside a timeout in the start function, but it didn't seem to have an effect.

Is there a way to keep the cursor and the draggable together somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change opacity. The hidden attr get off the element from "index".

```
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eEgTL/

Comment: This would hide the images, but the only reason I'm doing that is to collapse the items so more fit on the page.  Changing the opacity makes the images invisible, but they'll still occupy the same amount of space.  Imagine the fiddle with images 2x as large and in a scrollable column down the left-hand side of the page.  You'd only be able to see an item or two if the images are included (same with opacity 0), but if you display:none the images, they collapse in and more fit.

Comment: Hunn... I got it now. I will try something else.

Comment: I guess there is no way to do what you want without change your logic. You can see [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js#L168) that "start callback" is called after the size ajusted. And the position of elements changes after that. You can try replace the original code and add a beforeStart callback and then you hide the images.

Comment: A beforeStart callback prior to the size/position adjustments did exactly what I needed.  Thanks much!